# Blender eats up all memory and crashes upon simple small texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, memory-management

So this one is really infuriating me as I cannot figure it out. I've created a terrain with textures and a skybox in layer 1 just fine and all looks well. It's also very responsive and works great, not slow and laggy at all. I have plenty of memory free and blender reports using a total of 65MB of memory - system reports an overall 6GB of free RAM.

I wanted to add in some grass so I flipped to layer 2 which is empty at the moment and added in a plane then a very small 512 pixel transparent png and wired it up in cycles.

Well shortly after blender immediately starts eating up all of the memory up and eventually crashes. I simply cannot fathom why it's doing this. I've edited the images many times making them increasingly smaller with gimp but nothing works.

If I'm not on layer 2 it works just fine, switch to layer 2 and after a few seconds it stutters a bit, locks up the entire computer (mouse won't even move) followed by a full program crash and the release of many many gigabytes of memory.

Opening it up with a terminal doesn't reveal any information except a small printout from the Linux kernel saying it force closed it.

My specs are:

```
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.3-2-ARCH
Resolution: 1680x1050
DE: KDE 5.43.0 / Plasma 5.12.2
WM: KWin
CPU: Intel Core i7-3720QM @ 8x 3.6GHz [35.9°C]
GPU: GeForce GT 650M
RAM: 2167MiB / 7918MiB
```

I render in cycles but use my cpu, I only use my gpu for GUI rendering if that also helps any.

I've never had any problems up until now out of Blender in this regard and I've done lots of other stuff more intensive than this simple trivial task.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on another computer/OS? Sounds like a bug for sure.

Comment: @MikePan - Yes, as it turns out when I switched over to a mac the problem went away and acted normally. So maybe a bug on the Linux version. Thank you for the suggestion - I was so wrapped up in the problem it just never occurred to me to simply change OS lol.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have solved this issue on Windows 10. The problem was a driver corrupt file on my case.... I made a clean installation of the drivers and Blender now stays at normal rates. Between 180 MB and 200 MB of RAM.
I had this problem in Linux but I updated my drivers from Windows(dual boot) and problem was solved